remove Woocommerce "add to cart" to be "Download" button
I have a Wordprees website and I sell book  on my site, I want woocommerce replace "add to cart" button with "Download" button if
the product is free
user will find "download" button instant of "add to cart" button in product

You'll have to ask WooCommerce's support team for help with this. Third-party plugin support is off topic here.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
